# Is there a way to reassign a Range variable to a different range?

Tags: excel, vba

I am very new to VBA, having started programming it yesterday. I am writing a data processing program which requires keeping track of two cells, one on each spreadsheet. The code which reproduces the errors I am experiencing is below. When I call the sub moveCell() in sub Processor(), nothing happens to DIRow and DIColumn, and the code spits out error 1004 at the line indicated. I have tried using DICell = DICell.Offset(), but it returns the same error.

How can I redefine a Range variable to be a different cell?

```
'<<Main Processor Code>>'
Sub Processor()

Dim PDRow As Integer
Dim PDColumn As Integer
Dim DIRow As Integer
Dim DIColumn As Integer

PDRow = 1
PDColumn = 1
DIRow = 1
DIColumn = 1

Dim PDCell As Range
Dim DICell As Range

Set PDCell = Worksheets("Processed Data").Cells(PDRow, PDColumn)
Set DICell = Worksheets("Data Input").Cells(DIRow, DIColumn)

Call moveCell(2, 0, "Data Input")

End Sub

'<<Function which moves the cell which defines the range>>'
Sub moveCell(r As Integer, c As Integer, sheet As String)
    If sheet = "Processed Data" Then
        PDRow = PDRow + r
        PDColumn = PDColumn + c
        Set PDCell = Worksheets("Data Input").Cells(PDRow, PDColumn)
    ElseIf sheet = "Data Input" Then
        DIRow = DIRow + r '<<<<<<This line does nothing to DIRow's value
        DIColumn = DIColumn + c
        Set DICell = Worksheets("Data Input").Cells(DIRow, DIColumn) '<<<<<<This line causes error 1004
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: First step > add `Option Explicit` to the top of the module. Then read up on [scope](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/concepts/getting-started/understanding-scope-and-visibility). [This](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/141693/scope-of-variables-in-visual-basic-for-applications) is also good reading.

Comment: As you have it currently, in `moveCell()`, `Cells(DIRow, DIColumn)` will be `Cells(2,0)`...there is no `0` Column.  Also, if `moveCell()` is to be a range, I'd look in to making it a Function instead, e.g. `Function movecell(...) as Range`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell, you could instead use a quick Function instead.  There doesn't seem to be any difference in your `If` statement results in the `moveCell()` function, except which worksheet you're using.

We can make this simpler by referring to the `Range` you're passing to `moveCell`.

```
Option Explicit ' forces you to declare all variables
Sub something()

Dim PDCell As Range
Set PDCell = Worksheets("Processed Data").Cells(1, 1)

Dim DICell As Range
Set DICell = Worksheets("Data Input").Cells(1, 1)

PDCell.Select ' can remove
Set PDCell = moveCell(2, 0, PDCell, PDCell.Worksheet.Name)
PDCell.Select ' can remove

Worksheets(DICell.Worksheet.Name).Activate ' can remove
DICell.Select ' can remove
Set DICell = moveCell(5, 0, DICell, DICell.Worksheet.Name)
DICell.Select ' can remove

End Sub

Function moveCell(rowsToMove As Long, colsToMove As Long, cel As Range, ws As String) As Range
Set moveCell = Worksheets(ws).Cells(cel.Row + rowsToMove, cel.Column + colsToMove)
End Function
```

I've included some rows you don't need (which I've marked with a comment afterwards), but that will show you how the routine works.  You can step through with <kbd>F8</kbd> to help see it step-by-step.

Edit: Although, *you don't need a separate function at all*. Just use [`OFFSET()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Excel.Range.Offset).

```
Set PDCell = ...whatever originally
Set PDCell = PDCell.Offset([rows],[cols])
```

Comment: @BigBen - I got too excited about thinking how to create a function that returns a range and makes his code more efficient ...only to afterward realize `OFFSET()` already does that exactly :P

Comment: Thanks for the clear answer! I tweaked your code a little bit, and it works perfectly! My tweak is the same as putting `cel.Worksheet.Name` where `ws` is

Comment: @DanielLenshin ah, duh. You can remove the `ws` variable altogether. Didn't catch that ..but do realize you can just use `offset()`, no need to define a new function.